# Opening multiple windows at set times

Tags: python

Here are the notes for my program, which I use to outline what exactly I want the program to do:

1. Go to specific links at specific times. Ex. Go to Facebook at 12pm.
2. Login with username.
3. (OPTIONAL) Send alert to phone about each time logged in.

Only thing is, I'm relatively new in programming so I need a little help knowing where to start on creating this.

Comment: (1) Scheduler, (2) Selenium, and (3) a Twilio account

Answer (score 0):

I would use selenium if I were you. It allows you to automate web browser tasks, such as going to a site and logging in and such. You could keep a dictionary of sites, times, and usernames and use those accordingly. Sending an alert to your phone could be done in a number of ways. You could send an email using SMTP, a built-in python library, that would probably be the best method of communicating with other devices simply.